# Tomcat-8.0.32 not able to run on Mac

Tags: java, macos, tomcat

When I try to run Tomcat all I get is the below error.

> -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/Users/.../Tomcat-8.0.32/endorsed is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules.
>
> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>
> Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

I have to use Tomcat 8.0.32 because of other software I have to use. I have Java 8.181 installed but it is not letting me enable the endorsed option using JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS. Is there anywhere else I can change this or do I have to use a different version of java?

Comment: I have fix this. I didn't fully uninstall Java 10 when I was installing Java 8. All I had to run was **sudo rm -rf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk*.jdk** in the terminal and re-install 8.